# Check complex differentiability

Tags: complex-analysis, functional-analysis, derivatives, banach-spaces

I am trying to take a derivative w.r.t $z\in\mathbb{C}$ of the following map:

$z\mapsto \sum_{j=0}^{\infty}\lambda_{j} (T(\psi+zh))_{j}$

where $(\lambda_{j})$ is a bounded sequence, $T$ is a nonlinear operator on a complex Banach space (with $l^{1}$ norm, functions analytic on some open disc radius $r$), and both $\psi$ and $h$ belong to that space.

How do I take a derivative here? Does the usual chain rule apply? What confuses me is that I have to differentiate w.r.t. a variable, and then it's multiplied by a function… So by the chain rule I probably cannot say that the inner derivative is just $h$?

What makes me very confused is that I'm looking for a "normal" complex derivative, but not just of a function of a complex variable, but of an operator. 
Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the chain rule applies here, assuming $T$ is at least Gateaux differentiable. The derivative you consider is the direct analog of directional derivatives of multivariable calculus, $D_v f = \frac{d}{dt}f(x+tv)$ where $x,v$ are elements of vector space and $t$ is a scalar. Chain rule applies: $D_v f = \nabla f \cdot v$. Yes, the inner derivative can be described as $v$ (or $h$ in your case).

Same here. If $T$ has (complex) Gâteaux derivative $A$ at $\psi$, then *by definition* of this derivative we have 
$$T(\psi+zh) - T(\psi) = z A h +o(|z|),\quad z\to 0 \tag1$$
Here $A$ is a  bounded *linear* operator from the function space into $l^1$. The $o(|z|)$ term is something that goes to zero norm-wise, even if divided by $|z|$).

After that $T$ is paired with $\lambda \in l^\infty$, i.e., a continuous linear functional is applied to it. Applying $\lambda$ to both sides of (1) we get 
$$\langle \lambda, T(\psi+zh) - T(\psi) \rangle =  z \langle \lambda, A h \rangle +o(|z|),\quad z\to 0 \tag2$$
This $\langle \lambda, A h \rangle $ thing is the derivative.

Comment: @This_is_much_healthier, just one more question: in your answer, the fact that we are actually differentiating an infinite sum doesn't come up explicitly. Does it mean that with your solution I don't have to prove that the sum converges uniformly so that I can take the derivative inside? Thanks!

Comment: @GregVoit You don't. This was (sort of) already done when we showed that elements of $l_\infty$ are continuous linear functionals on $l^1$. The nature of this functional (infinite sum, integral, etc) does not come into play. As long as (1) holds, we can apply a functional to both sides of it. //  If you want, you can also replace $\lambda $ and $T$ with their composition $f = \lambda\circ T$, which is a nonlinear scalar-valued functional on the function space.  Then you are just differentiating that functional.

Comment: @This_is_much_healthier, thank you, I see. In the equation (1) (and later (2)), when you say $z\rightarrow 0$, is it equivalent if I say that $|z|<\delta$ for some $\delta$ small enough? I just thought since $z\rightarrow 0$ essentially means neighborhood of the origin in $\mathbb{C}$ (right?) I could replace it by a small open ball...

Comment: @GregVoit Yes, $z\to 0$ is the same as $|z|\to 0$.